# Entity over-generalisation on Api.ai

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

We’ve been having a great deal of difficulty with chatbot entities over-generalising on Api.ai, i.e. returning values that have not been specified for that entity when using the “Define Synonyms” feature on custom entities, even when the “Allow automated expansion” flag is turned off.

Our key example is an entity we use for confirming a user choice called confirm_accept. We had an entry: “that’s it”, with synonyms: “thats it”, “that is it”, “that’s it thanks”, “thats it thanks”, “that is it thanks”. This entity value was being returned unexpectedly in expressions where just a stray “it” was appearing.

In general, we have seen a lot of inappropriate entity generalisation which seems to indicate there is some form of stop word removal and stemming/lemmatization going on during entity identification... and which can’t be turned off.

This returns poor entity classifications, making it difficult to create entities for which very precise values are important, e.g. where a single word or character can make a big difference in meaning. Our key use case involves a lot of address processing, so it is important we get back only values we have specified.

Types of over-generalisations we’ve seen include:

- inappropriate identification of determiners (a, an, the, this, that, etc.) as part of entities: as in “it” returning “that’s it”
- stemmed words: as in stray mentions of “driving”, returning “drive” (a valid street type entity)
- inappropriate plural stems: a stray mention of “children” returning “child”, or a stray “will” returning “wills” (which in our case “child” and “wills” are street name entities, so we don’t want “children” or “will” to be returned)

This is currently making it difficult to create a production quality chatbot using the Api.ai service.

Anyone had more luck at either getting a response from Api.ai or solving the over-generalisation problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Entities are meant to extract information from conversation**: 
API.AI's entities are meant to be used to *extract* data from conversational input *not* parse different phrases and parts of speech.  For your examples (`that’s it`, `thats it`, `that is it`, `that’s it thanks`, `thats it thanks`, `that is it thanks`) all seem to indicate that the user's intent is to indicate that the last message from the API.AI agent was correct. For instances like these, it would be best to use these phrases as examples for an intent or an existing intent with other responses  indicating that the user wants to indicate that the last response was correct.

**API.AI captures entity tenses and plurals automatically**: To address your other concern (`driving` entity, returning `drive` value, `children` returning `child`, or `wills` returning `wills`): API.AI intentionally captures different tenses and plurals of entities to provide a better experience for users who many not know the exact entities you've entered in your database.  This allows users of your conversational app to have a natural conversation with your users and not require precise wording or